# Make that only members of a group can access a specific disk

Tags: permissions, partition

All members of group `vip` should be allowed to read,write,execute to a specific disk. Currently, only the logged in user is allowed to access such disk.

What is the correct way to allow members of group `vip` to read,write,execute to a specific disk?

Comment: do you have `root` access? can you provide `/etc/fstab/` info? As `root` you can `chgrp -R vip /<disk>`

Comment: What OS? What is output of `mount` and what is mount point?

Answer (score 1):

If you access the disk using a filemanager then the partition is mounted in:

```
/run/media/<username>/<label or uuid>
```

Only the user which used the filemanager has permissions to this partition.

To make the partition visible to others, you'll need to add it to `/etc/fstab`.

For example:

```
/dev/sdb1   /media/mystuff                ext4 defaults 1 2
```

In this example, the partition /dev/sdb1 is mounted on `/media/mystuff`. Note:an alternative (and safer) method is to use the `uuid`, or a `label`.

With this file edited for your particular setup the partition will be mounted every time the system boots.

If the filesystem on the partition understands users and groups you can add normal Linux users and groups to all files and directories.  This means that you can add the group `vip` to all files and directories with:

```
sudo chown -R .vip /media/mystuff
```

However, if the filesystem doesn't support users and groups, such as `fat32`, you can tell the system which user and group that all files on the partition belong to.  Replace `defaults` with `uid=<user-id>,gid=<group-id>` in the example above.

To get the `<user-id>` and `<group-id> use the`id` command:

```
$ id -u <user>
1005
$ id -g vip
1002
```

The numbers returned are the `<user-id>` and `<group-id>` respectively - they'll be different on your system.

Also, change the `ext4` to `vfat`, for a `fat32` partition and add the `auto` option so that it mounts on boot:

```
/dev/sdb1   /media/mystuff      vfat     auto,uid=1005,gid=1002 1 2
```

Now, everyone in group `vip` should be able to access your files.